# Always a Lamed with a Dagesh

Tags: torah-study, grammar-dikduk

I'm looking for the sources that the Minchat Shai uses here in his comment in Shemot 6:10 which is the very first time the Torah records the famous verse וַיְדַבֵּ֥ר יְהֹוָ֖ה אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֥ה לֵּאמֹֽר׃

אל משה לאמר. כתב המכלול בשער אותיות או"י למ"ד אל משה לאמר דגושה לעולם למ"ד אל משה ואל אהרן לאמר איננה דגושה לעולם עכ"ל. וכן מצאתי בספרים כ"י מדוייקים. וכתב א"ת למ"ד משה לאמר דגושה בכל התורה חוץ מן אחד בפסוק ויאמרו בני גד ובני ראובן פ' מטות והאריך הרבה בענין ואין כאן מקום להאריך:

Looking also for other sources that may explain why, except once in the Torah, a Lamed that follows the word Moshe has always a Dagesh in.

Comment: It's not any lamed, specifically the phrase משה לאמר always has a dagesh in the lamed (whenever משה has a connective trop mark)

Comment: Here is the א״ת source: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19342&st=&pgnum=13 at the bottom

Comment: Here's the michlol https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9C_(%D7%A8%D7%93%22%D7%A7)/%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%95%22%D7%99 (who knew it was on wikitext)

Comment: Interesting that in addition to the example mentioned (במדבר לב:כה) where משה (tipcha) is followed by לאמר (lamed w/o dagesh), this also happens in במדבר יז:כז (several Chumashim checked here including Simanim, Koren, Wikitext's Mikra al Pi HaMasora project, Mikraos Gedolos HaKeter).